# The only equivalence relations on $\mathbb{Z}$ that are compatible with the ring operations are congruences modulo $n$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: ring-theory, modular-arithmetic, integers, congruence-relations

It's (probably) a fairly basic result that the only equivalence relations on $\mathbb{Z}$ that are compatible with the ring operations are congruences modulo $n$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$... as it's usually stated without proof in more advanced works on algebra.

(This is a "completeness result"--if you'd like to call it that--of the more elementary fact (in the opposite direction) that congruences modulo $n$ are compatible with the ring operations on $\mathbb{Z}$. The only slightly tricky part of the reverse implication is to prove it for multiplication: $a_1 - a_2 = xn$ and $b_1 - b_2 = yn$ imply that $a_1 b_1 - a_2 b_2 = a_1 (b_1 - b_2) + b_2(a_1-a_2) = (a_1 y +  b_2x)n$.)

But to restate the problem at hand here, let $E$ be an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{Z}$ compatible with the ring operations, i.e E is reflexive, transitive, symmetric, and additionally that $a_1Ea_2$ and $b_1Eb_2$ imply that $(a_1+a_2)E(b_1+b_2)$ and $(a_1a_2)E(b_1b_2)$. Prove that there exist $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that for all integers $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, $aEb$ implies that $a-b = kn$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Is $0 \leq k \leq n$ intentional here?

Comment: @BimoAdityarahman: left out the -1 if that's what you meant...

Comment: For example, $\mathbb{Z}_3$ satisfies the premise, but for any chosen $n$, we can set $0$ and $3n^2$ as the counterexample of your hypothesis?

Comment: @BimoAdityarahman: yeah, sorry, I got it (the quotient) confused with the remainder...

Comment: More generally see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/16157/242)

Comment: @BillDubuque: if I understood that correctly, it suffices to show that $n\mathbb{Z}$ are the (all the) ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$, which seem to be Chrystomath's proof structure.

Comment: @Fizz That's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the set $Z:=\{a\in \mathbb{Z}:aE0\}$. The positive integers in this set have a minimum, call it $n$. (If the only element is $0$, then $E$ is the equality relation.)

One can then prove the following statements:

1. $Z=n\mathbb{Z}$ (by using the division algorithm).
2. $aEb\iff (a-b)E(b-b)\iff (a-b)E0\iff a-b=kn$.

Comment: I guess your point (2) is that this problem is equivalent to showing that the only ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ are $n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: One point that's unclear to me (from this sketch) is whether you have use the fact that E is compatible with multiplication or does the compatibility with addition (explicit in 2) suffice?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1301510/173347 is related to your first para, that $n\mathbb{Z}$ are the only subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ so there can't be any ideals besides those (and in this case all subgroups are ideals too.)

Comment: @Fizz Although the fact that E is compatible with multiplication is not directly used in the proof, this is misleading because in $\mathbb{Z}$ subgroups are automatically ideals. For any $a$, $na=0$, so if $a_1\sim a_2$ and $b_1\sim b_2$ then $a_1b_1=a_1+\cdots+a_1\sim a_2+\cdots a_2=a_2b_1= \cdots \sim a_2b_2$.

Answer (score 0):

To collect here a couple of my comments that maybe someone else finds useful on this matter:

- The problem is reduced to that of determining (all the) ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ [because](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_relation#Congruences_of_groups,_and_normal_subgroups_and_ideals) (as Howie phrased this):

> in a ring a congruence is determined if we know the ideal which is the congruence class containing the zero.

- There can be no more ideals than there are (additive) subgroups and $n\mathbb{Z}$ [are all](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1301510/173347) subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$.
- More generally, every integral & Euclidean domain is a principal ideal domain, or in Dummit and Foote's words:

> The first implication of a Division Algorithm for the integral domain $R$ is that it
> forces every ideal of $R$ to be principal. Every ideal in a Euclidean Domain is principal. More precisely, if $I$ is any nonzero ideal in the Euclidean Domain $R$ then $I$ = ($d$), where $d$ is any nonzero element of $I$ of minimum norm.

(For $\mathbb{Z}$ the absolute of an element value gives the norm.)